# Folder access permissions - how do they work?

Tags: permissions, groups

I wonder - why, when some folder has `read` or `read-write` permissions for `GROUP` (or `other`), the members of the `GROUP` (or `other`) can't access this folder?

I'm almost sure there is a logical explanation, but I can't find it. Let me give an example.

### Initial circumstances

**1.** There are two users, called **`admin`** and **`guest`**.

**2.** There is a folder, called **`/var/www/test-dir`**:

```
$ getfacl -pt /var/www/test-dir/
# file: /var/www/test-dir/
USER   root      rwx
GROUP  admin     r-x
other            r-x
```

**3.** Within these permissions all users are able to access the folder:

- `USER    root    rwx (7)` is **able** to access the folder.
- `GROUP   admin   r-x (5)` is **able** to access the folder.
- `other   guest   r-x (5)` is **able** to access the folder.

  ```
  guest@host:~$ cd /var/www/test-dir/
  guest@host:/var/www/test-dir$ ࢒
  ```

### Cases

**Case 1:** `other` has `r--` permissions but `admin` can't access the folder:

```
root@host:~# chmod 574 /var/www/test-dir/
```

- `USER    root    r-x (5)` is **able** to access the folder.
- `GROUP   admin   rwx (7)` is **able** to access the folder.
- **`other   guest   r-- (4)`**  is **unable to access** the folder.

  ```
  guest@host:~$ cd /var/www/test-dir
  bash: cd: /var/www/test-dir/: Permission denied
  ```

---

**Case 2:** `other` has `rw-` permissions but `guest` can't access the folder:

```
root@host:~# chmod 656 /var/www/test-dir/
```

- `USER    root    rw- (6)` is **able** to access the folder.
- `GROUP   admin   r-x (5)` is **able** to access the folder.
- **`other   guest   rw- (6)`** is **unable to access** the folder:

---

**Case 3:** `GROUP` has `r--` permissions but `admin` can't access the folder:

```
root@host:~# chmod 745 /var/www/test-dir/
```

- `USER    root    rwx (7)` is **able** to access the folder.
- **`GROUP   admin   r-- (4)`** is **unable to access** the folder.
- `other   guest   r-x (5)` is **able** to access the folder.

---

**Case 4:** `GROUP` has `rw-` permissions but `admin` can't access the folder:

```
root@host:~# chmod 467 /var/www/test-dir/
```

- `USER    root    r-- (4)` is **able** to access the folder.
- **`GROUP   admin   rw- (6)`**  is **unable to access** the folder.
- `other   guest   rwx (7)` is **able** to access the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folder permissions aren't the same as typical permissions. In a directory, permissions are as follows:

- **`r`**: Can the directory's contents be listed (like with `ls`)?
- **`w`**: Can the directory be modified (new files added, files deleted, renamed, etc)?
- **`x`**: Can the directory be *accessed* by `cd` and the like?

The `r` permission does not require `x` be set on a folder (you can `ls` an `r--` folder all you want), but you will not be able to see anything other than filenames:

```
ls: cannot access 'test/..': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'test/.': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'test/file': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ./
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ../
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file
```

The `w` permission does require `x` to be set in *all* cases. You will not be able to alter a directory with only `rw-` access to it.

Meanwhile, the `x` permission is essentially the master permission. In order to see file metadata (like permissions), navigate to the file, or even work on files inside the folder that you have write access to, you will need the `x` permission.

See the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#Examples) for some good examples of directory permissions.

As usual, the `root` account is automatically granted every permission under the sun.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be root or have execute ('x') permission to access a folder.