# Permission Denied in /var/www/public_html. I am member of www-data

Tags: permissions, apache2, groups

Hi just installed Apache2 on Ubuntu 20.04. Added myself to www-data group.
`id prateek`

```
uid=1000(prateek) gid=1000(prateek) groups=1000(prateek),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),33(www-data),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare)
```

changed the ownership and permission of /var/www/bihag.moops/public_html.

```
ls -l /var/www/bihag.moops/ 
total 4 
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 11 07:58 public_html
```

Folders inside public_html also belongs to the same group.

```
ls -l /var/www/bihag.moops/public_html/
total 8
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data  191 Aug 11 07:54 index.html
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 11 07:59 logs
```

Still can't write to public_html. Even though I am the member of the same group. Why this discrimination?

```
touch home.php
touch: cannot touch 'home.php': Permission denied
```

**Note:** Even though this is a local machine. I don't want to use 777 permission.

**Additionally:**

```
lsattr /var/www/
--------------e----- /var/www/bihag.moops
--------------e----- /var/www/html
```

And

```
lsattr /var/
--------------e----- /var/mail
--------------e----- /var/log
--------------e----- /var/www
```

Comment: If I become the owner of public_html how will it be possible for the webserver to write anything in there?

Comment: https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld will help you explore this problem.

Comment: I think you need to use *setgid bit* as it is shown here: [Fixing permission settings on html folder](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164046/566421). Another kind of solution is to remount the directory at another mount point with different owner by using *bindfs*, as it is shown here: [Setting up SFTP to log in to server with Filezilla](https://askubuntu.com/a/1024308/566421).

Comment: Thanks that did it. I also changed the ownership of public html to myself. You should write this as an answer, so I could help others too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing permission settings on html folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163995/fixing-permission-settings-on-html-folder)

Comment: Hi, GunJack. I'm glad to hear your problem is solved. Instead of duplicating the answer I've marked the question as possible duplication. If you want you could up-vote the related answer in order to tell the others it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check on the [extended attributes](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/chattr.htm) of `/var/www` (and its subdirectories), like so:

```bsh
$ lsattr /var/www # or /var/www/bihag.moops, or /var/www/bihag.moops/public_html
```

If the `i` (immutable) attribute is set, e.g. you see something like:

```
----i--------------- /var/www
```

then that could explain why you cannot create a new file in the directory even with the right permissions. In that case, you could remove the `i` attribute by doing:

```bsh
$ sudo chattr -i /var/www # or /var/www/bihag.moops, or /var/www/bihag.moops/public_html
```

Comment: No immutable attribute. It has an e attribute. I will update my question to reflect the output of these commands.