# apache won't index folder from another mount

Tags: permissions, mount, apache2, apache2.4, indexing

I'm trying to enable directory listing for a folder outside the web root, from a different local ext4 mount that uses Basic Authentication, but I'm getting an empty list and no logged errors. What's strange is that if I put in the known location of a file under this directory in my browser, it downloads the file just fine.

> [image]

Here's my `example.conf` file:

```
<virtualhost *:80>

  ServerAdmin donotreply@blah.com
  ServerName  example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com


  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/apachelogs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/apachelogs/access.log combined

  Alias /blah2 "/blah1/blah2"
    <Location /blah2>
              Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
              IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
    </Location>


</virtualhost>
```

And here's my `.htaccess`

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/home/myusername/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

Also, I've commented `IndexIgnore` out in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/autoindex.conf`

```
#IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# RCS CVS *,v *,t
```

I've run `chmod -R 755 /blah1/blah2`, and `chgrp -R www-data /blah1/blah2` and `chmod a+x -R /blah1/blah2`. The folder owner is a member of www-data.  If I run `sudo usermod -a -G www-data myusername` I can browse and read all files and folders just fine.

Doing some testing, my configuration works fine if I move /blah1/blah2 under my home directory and change the alias. There's something about it being on another mount that is messing up mod_autoindex, even though apache can clearly read the files themselves.  Removing authentication doesn't help.  With `LogLevel warn` I get no logged errors. After changing my LogLevel to trace4, [here's my error log](https://pastebin.com/uB2kctQi).

Here's the mount line from `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=[theuuid] /blah1 ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,errors=remount-ro    0    0
```

**EDIT**
Last note: confirming that www-data can read and write to my folder, I made the following php script:

```
<?php

mkdir ("testdir");
var_dump(scandir('.'));

?>
```

The result: directory testdir is created with owner www-data:www-data, and the list of directories and files is dumped as a variable.

**EDIT2**
I've run the following commands to set permissions correctly:

```
chmod 755 /blah1/blah2
chmod 755 /blah1
find /blah1/blah2 -type d -exec chgrp www-data {} +
find /blah1/blah2 -type d -exec chmod o+rx {} +
find /blah1/blah2 -type d -exec chmod g+rwxs {} +
```

Still the same result.

Comment: What about using `LogLevel debug` and then checking log files?

Comment: No new info with debug. https://pastebin.com/xu1bUuvB

Comment: Based on your logs. I think your issue is the index cannot access your .htaccess. try to copy the content of .htaccess into <Directory />

Comment: Tried that, same result.

Comment: Also, removing authentication completely didn't change the end result.  It grants everyone access but shows no files.

Comment: @user255406 the log said `authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)` . That's mean nothing grants access for users, did you add `authBasicProvider file` into <Directory />

Comment: To simplify the conversation, here's the error log with LogLevel debug and auth removed.  Same result.  It's not an auth problem. https://pastebin.com/bhCqsydg

Comment: @Lety I have the fstab entry above and the chmod commands above. Can you explain how I'd verify this further?

Comment: Have you tried using `<Directory /blah1/blah2>` instead of `<Location /blah2>`?

Comment: Yes, no change.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that could be changed in your configuration. In order to help you, I'm providing here the following guide, based on the default Apache2's configuration.

### Deal with the file system permissions

In order to access the files, the Apache's user `www-data` needs to have read permissions to the files and read-execute [permissions](https://askubuntu.com/a/913959/566421) to the directories, also in this number read-execute permissions to the whole path. If you do not have any special requirements, I would suggest you to use the other users permissions.

Let's assume the directory you want to index via the web server is named `bar` and it is located in the home directory of the user `foo`. By default he directories `/home` and `/home/foo` must have `755` permissions. The last bit in the [octal](https://askubuntu.com/q/152001/566421) number `755` means all other users have read-execute permissions (content rad access) to the files inside `/home/foo`.

So let's create our directory `/home/foo/bar` and let's assure it (and its path) has `r-x` permissions for the other users:

```bsh
mkdir -p /home/foo/bar                            # create the directory
find /home/foo/bar -type d -exec chmod o+rx {} +  # apply o+rx for the dirs recursively
sudo chmod o+rx /home /home/foo                   # this step is optional
```

Now let's create three test files and assure they have read permissions for the other users:

```bsh
touch /home/foo/bar/file.{1..3}                  # create three empty test files
find /home/foo/bar -type f -exec chmod o+r {} +  # apply o+r for the files recursively
```

---

In order to allow `www-data` to write content in `/home/foo/bar` you can change the group ownership of the directory and add `rwxs` group permissions ([more details](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164046/566421)):

```bsh
find /home/foo/bar -type d -exec chgrp www-data {} +
find /home/foo/bar -type d -exec chmod g+rwxs {} +
```

Test by creating another three empty files:

```bsh
sudo -u www-data touch /home/foo/bar/file.{4..6}
```

### Deal with the Apache's configuration

By default, within the main configuration file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, for security reasons, the access to the root directory `/` is restricted. I would suggest you to do not override these rules via the virtual host configuration and remove `<Directory />` tags (and the enclosed directives).

In particular, if you are creating an Alias to a directory outside of your `DocumentRoot`, you may need to explicitly permit access to the target directory (source [Apache Module mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)).

Let's first create `.htpasswd` file with enough permissions ([add more security by using 2FA - p.6](https://askubuntu.com/a/939241/566421)):

```bsh
htpasswd -c /home/foo/.htpasswd foo               # authentication for the username 'foo'
chmod 400 /home/foo/.htpasswd                     # restricted the permissions
sudo chown www-data:www-data /home/foo/.htpasswd  # change the ownership
```

According to the above, the relevant part of you virtual host configuration file should be something like this:

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Other configuration directives

    Alias "/bar" "/home/foo/bar"

    <Directory "/home/foo/bar">
            #Require all granted
            Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
            IndexOptions +FancyIndexing

            # Allow using of a .htaccess files
            AllowOverride All

            # This section could be moved in .htaccess file
            <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>

                <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
                    AuthType Basic
                    AuthName "Type some hints here..."
                    AuthUserFile /home/foo/.htpasswd
                </IfModule>

                Require valid-user

            </IfModule>

    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the relevant modules and restart Apache2 to apply the new configuration:

```bsh
sudo a2enmod authz_core authz_user authn_file
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

### Sample result

[image]

### Update:

I'm assuming the problem belongs to file system's permissions issue. Probably the most easiest way, to solve it, is to mount the target directory inside the DocumentRoot directory by using `bindfs` as it is described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1024308/566421).

### Working solution:

Here's the final solution: abandon the idea of getting Alias to work correctly for my externally mounted folder and instead take @pa4080's workaround advice and use`bindfs` to mount the folder to /blah2 in the webroot. I was unsuccessful in getting /etc/fsab to correctly initialize my bind, so I decided to write an init script for the task.

First, install bindfs:

```bsh
apt-get update
apt-get install bindfs
mkdir /var/www/example.com/blah2
```

Next I created a script file `/var/www/scripts/blahbind.sh` to be run on startup:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
bindfs -o force-user=www-data,perms=a=rX /blah1/blah2 /var/www/example.com/blah2
```

Then give it correct permissions:

```bsh
chmod 750 /var/www/scripts/blahbind.sh
chmod +x /var/www/scripts/blahbind.sh
```

Next I created a service script:

```bsh
vi /etc/systemd/system/blahbind.service
```

With the contents:

```bsh
[Unit]
Requires=mydrive.mount
After=mydrive.mount
Description=bind /blah1/blah2 to example.com/blah2 folder

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/scripts/blahbind.sh
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note, `mydrive.mount` should be replaced with the drive of the `/blah1/blah2` folder.  Get a list of mounts with `systemctl list-units --type=mount`.

Confirm that the service script works by running

```bsh
sudo service blahbind start
```

Then enable the service to persist on reboot with:

```bsh
sudo systemctl enable blahbind.service
```

And then, my simplified Location block, sans `Alias` in `example.com.conf`

```bsh
   <Location /blah2>
            Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
            IndexOptions +FancyIndexing
   </Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. If I follow your tutorial for a directory in my home folder it works perfectly, but if that folder is on another mounted drive I get the same result. I added the code I ran to EDIT2.

Comment: Hello, @user255406, IMO this is permissions issue. I've added a reference to a possible workaround to my answer.

Comment: Using the `bindfs` workaround, I was able to get everything working correctly. To me, this says it's not really a permissions issue at all.

Comment: Ultimately, the workaround is a working solution for me. Would you like to expand your Update section to explain the method here? (I used bindfs and added mounting it as a systemd service to bring it up on reboot)

Comment: Hi, @user255406, I would like to expand the update section, I will have an access to a computer tomorrow morning. You are welcome, if you want to add some update to the answer, Stack Exchange is a team game at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Apache will need execute rights for all directories, your case `/blah1` and `/blah2`. If it encounters a directory it doesn't have group execute rights for a directory it will not do the listing.

You probably need to modify `/blah1` to either have public execute rights or chown `www-data` to be it's group with group execution right, eg. `g+x`

Comment: I added the code I added onto EDIT2. apache can execute, but still no dice.

Comment: Execute rights for the directory, which is listing rights essentially.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on `example.conf`, you have `/var/www/example.com` as Document Root and `/blah1/blah2` as Directory ext4 mounted.

Let's assumed the Document Root Symlinked to your Directory mounted. now we need confirm the location of our Document Root. we will copy the files using `rsync`. it will dump the contents into the mount point instead of transferring it into a containing `html` location.

```
$sudo rsync -av /var/www/example.com/html /blah1/blah2
```

**Now we are ready to update the configuration**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

...
...
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
...
...
Alias /blah2 "/blah1/blah2"
<Directory "/blah1/blah2">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
    Require valid-user
    ...
    ...
    #to ensure the DocumentRoot is updated in rewrites or aliases to reflect the changes at the new location.
    RewriteEngineon
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ filename.html
    ...
</Directory>

<VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to enable `mod_rewrite` see this [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Finally we check the syntax and Restart your Apache.

```
$sudo apachectl configtest
$sudo systemctl reload apache
```

Hope this helpfully.